# python matching CSV values from a variable against a CSV file issue

Tags: python, json, csv

Using an API query , I received a huge JSON response with more attributes.

I'm trying to parse only certain fields from the response in a comma separated CSV format.

```
    >>> import json
    >>> resp = { "status":"success", "msg":"", "data":[ { "website":"https://www.blahblah.com", "severity":"low", "location":"unknown", "asn_number":"AS4134 Chinanet", "longitude":121.3997000000, "epoch_timestamp":1530868957, "id":"c1e15eccdd1f31395506fb85" }, { "website":"https://www.jhonedoe.co.uk/sample.pdf", "severity":"low", "location":"unknown", "asn_number":"AS4134 Chinanet", "longitude":120.1613998413, "epoch_timestamp":1530868957, "id":"933bf229e3e95a78d38223b2" } ] }
    >>> response = json.loads(json.dumps(resp))
    >>> KEYS = 'website', 'asn_number' , 'severity'
    >>> x = []
    >>> for attribute in response['data']:
            csv_response = ','.join(attribute[key] for key in KEYS)
            print csv_response
```

While printing the "csv_response" which gave the `values` of the key which was queried.

```
https://www.blahblah.com,AS4134 Chinanet,low
https://www.jhonedoe.co.uk/sample.pdf,AS4134 Chinanet,low
```

Now , I have a CSV file in `/tmp/` directory.

```
/tmp$cat 08_july_2018.csv
http://download2.freefiles-10.de,AS24940 Hetzner Online GmbH,high
https://www.jhonedoe.co.uk/sample.pdf,AS4134 Chinanet,low
http://download2.freefiles-11.de,AS24940 Hetzner Online GmbH,high
www.solener.com,AS20718 ARSYS INTERNET S.L.,low
https://www.blahblah.com,AS4134 Chinanet,low
www.telewizjairadio.pl,AS29522 Krakowskie e-Centrum Informatyczne JUMP Dziedzic,high
```

I'm trying to check/match if values which we got from JSON response "csv_response" is present in "/tmp/08_july_2018.csv" file .

From "`csv_response`" values , If any one of the line values matched from `08_july_2018.csv` , I'll be marking the condition as as "Passed".

Any suggestions on how to match the CSV values from a variable against a file present on `/tmp/` directory and make the condition as passed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Pandas (code below is from jupyter notebook). Pandas will give you a lot of flexibility on matching columns from csv.

You need to add a header to the csvfile you want to read, so add:

```
website,asn,severity
```

to the 08_july_2018.csv file

```
import pandas as pd
import json

resp = { "status":"success", "msg":"",
         "data":[ { "website":"https://www.blahblah.com", 
                    "severity":"low",
                    "location":"unknown",
                    "asn_number":"AS4134 Chinanet", 
                    "longitude":121.3997000000, 
                    "epoch_timestamp":1530868957, 
                    "id":"c1e15eccdd1f31395506fb85" },
                  { "website":"https://www.jhonedoe.co.uk/sample.pdf", 
                    "severity":"low",
                    "location":"unknown",
                    "asn_number":"AS4134 Chinanet", 
                    "longitude":120.1613998413, 
                    "epoch_timestamp":1530868957, 
                    "id":"933bf229e3e95a78d38223b2" } ] }


t1 = pd.DataFrame(resp['data'])
t1.set_index('website', inplace=True)
print(t1) 

t2 = pd.read_csv('/tmp/08_july_2018.csv')
t2.set_index('website', inplace=True)
print(t2) 

# You try to check if one is present in the other. You can do that
# by querying the resulting (t3) dataframe holding all records
# mathing on the key (website). By selecting all rows that have
# equal severity you have those records. Extend/modify this query for
# the fields you want to match on. The columns of the first dataframe
# git the extension _1, the other dataframe _2. So, the colums with
# the same name in the original date now have these extension to 
# distinguish them
# If you want all rows that have a equal severity:
#   the query is: (t3['severity_1'] == t3['severity_2'])
# if you only want the 'low' severity:
#   (t3['severity_1'] == t3['severity_2']) & (t3['severity'] == 'low')
t3 = pd.concat([ t1.add_suffix('_1'), t2.add_suffix('_2')], axis=1)
t3['MTCH'] = t3[(t3['severity_1'] == t3['severity_2'])]['asn_number_1']
t3.dropna(inplace=True)
print(t3['MTCH'].values)
```

Gives:

```
...
['AS4134 Chinanet' 'AS4134 Chinanet']
```

or iter over all matching records and select the fields you need from the row:

```
for i, row in t3[(t3['severity_1'] == t3['severity_2'])].iterrows():
   print(i, row['severity_2']) # add other fields from t3
```

Comment: hootnot : Thanks for the suggesting to use pandas. But i have a query here , t3['MTCH'] = t3[(t3['severity_1'] == 'low') & (t3['severity_2'] == 'low')]['asn_number_1'] Im not able to understand this condition. Can you please help me with understanding ?

Comment: see the code, I've added some text, changed the query too